# adding static method to enum scala

Tags: java, scala, enums

I have a class in java in which I have given some constants as enum and I have a static method which returns a random value of enum as follows

```
import java.util.Random;

public enum Highway {

    NH4,
    NH17,
    NH27,
    NH28;

    public static Highway getRandomHighway(){
        Random random = new Random();
        return values()[random.nextInt(values().length)];
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve the same in Scala. I have tried as follows

```
import scala.util.Random

object Highway extends Enumeration {

 val NH4,NH17,NH27,NH28 = Value



 def getRandomHighway(): Highway.Value = {

   Highway.values.toVector(new Random().nextInt(Highway.values.size))

 }
```

I want to know whether it is the correct approach for the above java class in scala

Comment: Yeah that's fine

Comment: You could extract `new Random` to a private field.